# [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: context is not defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, echarts

I am making a web page using **vue**.

I would like to use **Echarts** in this web page and insert a nice looking [3D geographic map](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=animating-contour-on-globe&gl=1).

But this page keeps having an error:*[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: context is not defined"*.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCN00.png)
the detailed code is here.

```html
<template>
  <el-row :gutter="20" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <el-col :span="24">
      <el-card class="box-card">
        <div id="Earth" :style="{ height: '770px' }"></div>
      </el-card>
    </el-col>
  </el-row>
</template>

<script>
import * as echarts from "echarts";
import "echarts-gl";

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.drawEarth();
  },
  methods: {
    drawEarth() {
      var ROOT_PATH =
        "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/apache/echarts-website@asf-site/examples";

      var chartDom = document.getElementById("Earth");
      var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
      var option;

      ...

      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = 4096;
      canvas.height = 2048;
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.lineWidth = 0.5;
      context.strokeStyle = config.color;
      context.fillStyle = config.color;
      context.shadowColor = config.color;
      $.when(
        $.getScript(
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-array@2.8.0/dist/d3-array.js"
        ),
        $.getScript(
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-contour@2.0.0/dist/d3-contour.js"
        ),
        $.getScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-geo@2.0.1/dist/d3-geo.js"),
        $.getScript(
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-timer@2.0.0/dist/d3-timer.js"
        )
      ).done(...);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You should provide your code where you calling Echarts

Comment: Sorry for the omission of the code. Now it's being put up

Comment: Try to add `var context; ` under `var option;`

Comment: Problem solved, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved by the hint of *fatm*, who commented. After I added `var context`, another problem arose:[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined", But this problem is much more manageable. I just `import $ from 'jquery';` at the top of `<script>`, and the effect is really amazing!!!